# when trying to append and remove any element to a list it skips one particular value in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to replace '.hpp' extension with '.h' extension. But the problem as soon as i tried to add "filenames.remove(i_new)" line, it skips one particular value "sample.hpp".
Here's my code:

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out",]
# Generate newfilenames as a list containing the new filenames
# using as many lines of code as your chosen method requires.
for i in filenames:
    if i[-3:] == "hpp":
        print(i)
        i_new = i[:-3]+"h"
        print(i_new)
        filenames.append(i_new)
        print(filenames)
for i in filenames:
    if i[-3:] == "hpp":
        print(i)
        filenames.remove(i)
        print(filenames)

print('new_filenames', filenames)
```

Here's the output:

```
stdio.hpp
stdio.h
['program.c', 'stdio.hpp', 'sample.hpp', 'a.out', 'math.hpp', 'hpp.out', 'stdio.h']
sample.hpp
sample.h
['program.c', 'stdio.hpp', 'sample.hpp', 'a.out', 'math.hpp', 'hpp.out', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h']
math.hpp
math.h
['program.c', 'stdio.hpp', 'sample.hpp', 'a.out', 'math.hpp', 'hpp.out', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'math.h']
stdio.hpp
['program.c', 'sample.hpp', 'a.out', 'math.hpp', 'hpp.out', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'math.h']
math.hpp
['program.c', 'sample.hpp', 'a.out', 'hpp.out', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'math.h']
new_filenames ['program.c', 'sample.hpp', 'a.out', 'hpp.out', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'math.h']
```

Answer (score 0):

i can use:

```
new_filenames = [i.replace('.hpp','.h') for i in filenames]
print('new_filenames', newfilenames)
```

and the output is:

```
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']
```

Here's another way, with 'hpp.hpp':

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp","hpp.hpp" ,"sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
newfilenames = []
#  newfilenames as a list containing the new filenames

for i in filenames:
    if i[-4:] == ".hpp":
        i = i[:-2]
        newfilenames.append(i)
    else:  newfilenames.append(i) 

print(newfilenames)
```

and the output is:

```
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'hpp.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']
```

But can anyone help me what i am missing out???

Comment: Did you consider the case when the file name is `hpp.hpp` ?

Comment: hpp.hpp worked on the answerd program. but if i do that with the program described in the question, it does solve sample.h, but skipped hpp.hpp value while removing or appending.

Comment: new_filenames = [i.replace('.hpp','.h') for i in filenames]
print('new_filenames', newfilenames)   -- this code doesn't skip hpp.hpp